# Invalid number of arguments in useReducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-reducer

```
export function React.useReducer<(state: PasswordResetFormState, action: PasswordResetAction) => PasswordResetFormState,PasswordResetFormState>reducer: (state: PasswordResetFormState, action: PasswordResetAction) => PasswordResetFormState,     initializerArg: PasswordResetFormState,     initializer: (arg: PasswordResetFormState) => ReducerStateWithoutAction<(state: PasswordResetFormState, action: PasswordResetAction) => PasswordResetFormState>):    [ReducerStateWithoutAction<(state: PasswordResetFormState, action: PasswordResetAction) => PasswordResetFormState>, DispatchWithoutAction]
An alternative to useState.
useReducer is usually preferable to useState when you have complex state logic that involves multiple sub-values. It also lets you optimize performance for components that trigger deep updates because you can pass dispatch down instead of callbacks.
Version:
16.8.0
See also:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer 
  react
`useReducer(reducer: R, initialState: ReducerState , initializer?: undefined): [ReducerState , Dispatch  >]`, `useReducer(reducer: R, initializerArg: ReducerStateWithoutAction , initializer?: undefined): [ReducerStateWithoutAction , DispatchWithoutAction]`, `useReducer(reducer: R, initializerArg: I & ReducerState , initializer: (arg: (I & ReducerState )) => ReducerState ): [ReducerState , Dispatch  >]`, `useReducer(reducer: R, initializerArg: I, initializer: (arg: I) => ReducerState ): [ReducerState , Dispatch  >]`
```

I am getting the above typescript error in my usereducer hook.

```
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(
    passwordResetReducer,
    initialPasswordResetFormState
  );
```

Invalid number of arguments, expected 3.

```
export const passwordResetReducer = (
  state: PasswordResetFormState,
  action: PasswordResetAction
): PasswordResetFormState => {
  switch (action.case) {
    default:
      return { ...state, [action.field]: action.value };
  }
};

export const initialPasswordResetFormState: PasswordResetFormState = {
  email: "",
  password1: "",
  password2: "",
  auth: "",
};

export interface PasswordResetFormState {
  email: string;
  password1: string;
  password2: string;
  auth: string;
}

export enum PasswordResetActionCase {
  GENERAL = "GENERAL",
}

export type PasswordResetAction = {
  case: PasswordResetActionCase.GENERAL;
  value: string;
  field: string;
};
```

I have spent ages on this, google returns nothing and I'm at a complete loss. If anyone can notice anything obvious in the code that should be changed I would hugely appreciate the help. I have multiple forms setup in the same way, and the error is common across every single one of them. I first noticed the errors when someone else in the same codebase shared their screen, they weren't showing up in my webstorm. After a fresh installation they came up for me, and I have spent the entire night trying to fix them to no avail.

[image: type never on state]

State also shows as type never in the usereducer initialisation

solved - running npm install --save @types/react removes the errors

Comment: Not sure this will fix or not but I think the field type in PasswordResetAction should be as below

`export type PasswordResetAction = {
  case: PasswordResetActionCase.GENERAL;
  value: string;
  field: keyof PasswordResetFormState;
};`

Comment: @Phani That didn't fix it but I think that will be a simple to solution to another problem I was stuck on for a while with the dispatch typing, so thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE:**

It seems like the correct way to approach this would be to type the `useReducer` call itself:

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer<PasswordResetFormState, any>(reducer, initialState);
```

**ORIGINAL:**

I had this issue, and what seemed to fix it is to type the initializer argument to the `useReducer` function as `ReducerState`.

```
const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState as ReducerState<PasswordResetFormState>);
```

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick for me. I ended up using `as ReducerState<any>`, since I was not using an interface.